# How to store a Javascript GET response once a day?

Tags: php, javascript, performance, caching

I'm making a website that calls SoundCloud's API from Javascript, and the response takes about 7 seconds. What I want to do is to store the response somehow, and for the next 24 hours just use the response I already downloaded. The data shouldn't change more than once every day or so anyway, and this will significantly speed things up rather than making the call every time someone loads the page.

Is there a way to store it in text on my server using PHP? I don't have a database at all.

Thanks for the help, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: You can store it in text file, fairly easy to do. Using file_put_contents is probably the easiest way http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: You could store it in a file, for example /tmp/soundcloud_api_call_result.txt or even better you could store it in the APC cache if your server has that installed.

Comment: Well you shouldn't have to worry about this. This the web-browsers job to cache the API '.js' file and should re-download it whenever it gets changed on the server-side.

Comment: @dbuss Are you talking about caching the [JS API file](http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js) correct?

Comment: If you want to store the response in Javascript, try `localStorage` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: @KentPawar I doubt it. The OP said they are making a specifically API call and cache it's response, not cache the actual API file

Comment: @Ian Yup, I misread the question.

Comment: @dbuss1 Will authentication be required for making the request? How is it handled? If no, then a simple curl request would do the trick.

Comment: @KentPawar No problem, just wanted to point it out. Although a seemingly simple question, it's not completely clear

Comment: @dbuss1 Is there anything specific that you are passing to the API call that differentiates each call or is there one major call you're making that every single user can share? I know you are requesting this all be done with PHP, but your answer can help confirm/reject whether PHP is the right choice

Comment: I actually don't care if it's PHP or not, I just figured that was the best choice. I actually need to make about 10 calls each day at about the same time. (I need a separate call for each genre of music for different pages). SoundCloud does have some authentication, I just need to pass my client_id with the URL in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cron job that runs every day getting the js you need.

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://www.page.com/lib.js > my.js
```